# Identify S447 T0220 component

Tags: identification, component-failure

One component on this board has eluded me.  It is marked S447 horizontally at top,  the letters MEX down the right an J6 at the bottom.  The T logo is stylized with a swooping top.  Searching for the manufacturer has eluded me as well.

[image]

I appreciate any assistance identifying this component.

Comment: The part in the picture is marked S447.

Comment: And I had it incorrect in the body as well.  Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching the part for a while and searching up the logo, it's by Teccor Electronics which is now owned by Littelfuse. However searching up the catalog, I can't seem to find anything that fits the 3 number naming scheme. However that S in the front most certainly means that part is a SCR. This is all I got. It's probably a very old part. Perhaps talk to Littelfuse support.